# Ambito de variables javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery

Como estan amigos?

Me cuesta un poco entender el ambito de las variables que supongo es mi problema en el codigo y no termino de hacerlo funcionar.

En este caso deseo acceder al valor de (x) fuera de la funcion retornoInfo(respuesta). Para ello probé hacer un return de este valor y llamar la funcion dentro de otra variable pero no tuve ningun exito.

El valor de (x) quiero usarlo para seleccionar un option de formulario.

```javascript
$(".tablaUsuarios").on("click", ".btn_editar_usuario", function(){


    var idUsuario = $(this).attr("id_user_editar");

    
    var datos = new FormData();

    datos.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);


    $.ajax({

        url:"ajax/usuarios2.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function retornoInfo(respuesta) {

            var x = respuesta['rol'];
            
            console.log(x);// puedo traer el valor solamente en el ambito local
        

            $("#id_usuario").val(respuesta["id"]);// aqui estoy rellenando  el input con el valor que trae (respuesta)
            $("#nom_ape_editar").val(respuesta["nombre"]); // aqui estoy rellenando el input con el valor que trae (respuesta)

            return x;//retornar x para utilizarlo fuera de la funcion retornoInfo
        }
        
    })
    var valor_rol = retornoInfo();

    $("#rol_user_editar option[value='"+ valor_rol +"']").attr("selected","selected");

    
    $("#editarUsuario").css("display", "block");
    $("#listaUsuario").css("display","none");
    
    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por norma general, una variable sólo es accesible desde el punto en el que se declara, si la declaras dentro de una función, no podrás obtener su valor fuera de la misma...

```javascript
$(".tablaUsuarios").on("click", ".btn_editar_usuario", function(){


    var idUsuario = $(this).attr("id_user_editar");


    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);
    var rol;

    $.ajax({
      url:"ajax/usuarios2.ajax.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: datos,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function retornoInfo(respuesta) {
        rol = respuesta['rol'];        
        console.log(rol);
    
        $("#id_usuario").val(respuesta["id"]);
        $("#nom_ape_editar").val(respuesta["nombre"]);
        $("#rol_user_editar option[value='"+ rol +"']").attr("selected","selected");
    }
    
  });


  $("#editarUsuario").css("display", "block");
  $("#listaUsuario").css("display","none");
})
```

Al declarar la variable rol fuera de la función, ahora podrás usarla en otros lugares del script, pero en tu caso, yo el cambio lo haría en el success del ajax, pues podría pasarte que se ejecutase de forma asíncrona y no obtuvieses el valor del rol hasta más tarde de tener que utilizarlo.

A modo de recomendación, siempre que puedas evita usar variables con un ámbito mayor del necesario, al final están ocupando memoria y es mejor generar funciones que retornen un valor y luego asignar ese valor a otra variable.

Comment: Hola Oscar pude avanzar muy bien con las recomendaciones que me diste. Muchas gracias

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha resultado útil puedes puntuarla y marcarla como aceptada para que lo vean los demás usuarios que busquen una respuesta similar.

Comment: Hola Oscar me fue util tu ayuda y ya marque en aceptado muchas gracias!!!